# Unable to save NSMutableArray of my class to file (IOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, serialization, nsmutablearray

Can't find out why my code doesn't work. Please help someone.

I created my own class, implemented NSCoding protocol. Do not know what i miss or wrong.

**Here is saving code**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Currency.plist"]; 

Item * item = [[Item alloc] init];
item.x = 3; item.y = 5; item.type = (TType) 3; item.isSelected = NO;

NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:item];

[array fileName atomically:YES]  // ( Doesn't Save the file ,returns NO);
```

**Here is the code of my class**
**.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 

enum TType 
{
    kNone = 0, 
    KFirst = 1,
    ....
}; 

@interface Item : NSObject <NSCoding>{

}  

@property (nonatomic) int x;
@property (nonatomic) int y;
@property (nonatomic) enum TType type;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isSelected;

@end
```

**.m**

```
@implementation Item
@synthesize x, y , type , isSelected;

#pragma mark NSCoding Protocol

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;
{
  [encoder encodeInt32:[self x] forKey:@"x"];
  [encoder encodeInt32:[self y] forKey:@"y"];
  [encoder encodeInt32:[self type] forKey:@"type"];
  [encoder encodeBool:[self isSelected] forKey:@"isSelected"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder;
{
    if ( ![super init] )
        return nil;

    [self setX:[decoder decodeInt32ForKey:@"x"]];
    [self setY:[decoder decodeInt32ForKey:@"y"]];
    [self setType:(TType)[decoder decodeInt32ForKey:@"color"]];
    [self setIsSelected:[decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"isSelected"]];

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471830/why-nsuserdefaults-failed-to-save-nsmutabledictionary-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll find your answer at: [objects conforming to nscoding will not writetofile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352032/objects-conforming-to-nscoding-will-not-writetofile)

i.e. you can't serialize your `Item` class to a property list, since it isn't a property list object (`NSString`, `NSData`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`).

See the documentation for [`writeToFile:atomically:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile:atomically:):

> This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects before writing out the file, and returns `NO` if all the objects are not property list objects, since the resultant file would not be a valid property list.

Comment: Thanks!:) As this worked perfectly [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:array toFile:fileName]